# Windows XP - Physical memory dumping

Tags: windows-xp, bsod, sp2, intel-core2

I have Windows XP Professional installed on my desktop. It shows the following errors - physical memory dumping blue screen:

[image]

[image]

This isn't a new problem; I've been facing this problem ever since I bought the system. Initially the maintenance guy said it was a faulty hard drive - I've had it replaced three times already in the past year.

The system gets very slow after using it for around 2-3 months, then these errors crop up and I have to reinstall Windows to stop the errors. However on this occasion it's only been a week yet the blue screen has shown three times.

What could be the cause of the error?

My PC is an assembled machine: a Core 2 Duo with Gigabyte motherboard, 1GB ram, 160GB Seagate HDD.

**Edit:** A new error recently popped up - what should I do now?

[image]

Comment: my image tags dont show up, here are the image links :
1) http://www.twitpic.com/10cef4
2) http://www.twitpic.com/10cejc
3) http://www.twitpic.com/10ce9m

Comment: pics added in.  pics 1 & 2 appear to be of the same error so i only added 1 & 3.

Comment: they seem the same error but it happened on 2 different occassions so i put them both up. thnx

Comment: out of interest, how did you get the pic of the blue screen?

Comment: using my phone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also can come from a faulty ventilation or a faulty RAM (less likely). Manually inspect the temperature of the North and South bridge and check if the fans are running normally. You can also execute a RAM test application.

Comment: RAM tests are ok. wats the north south bridge?? sorry but m not familiar with the terminology? n temp checking, do u mean i check the temp from the BIOS?

Comment: The North and the South bridge are the most important chips at your motherboard. They're also the biggest two. I've seen some motherboards from manufacturers like Asus that have inadequate refrigeration. As one of those chips has the disk controller inside this could lead to problems like the one you have. I mean opening the case and checking the temp putting your finger on them. They should be warm but not hot.

Comment: Be careful with what you do if you're not used to electronics. You have to do the check with the system powered on. Better an hour after it has been powered.

Comment: i havn't touchd them with power on but aftr using the system for an hour or two, i powered off and touchd the chips n they were hot not warm, does this indicate a problem???

Comment: Mmm, it depends, they should be warm. If they burn it's the problem you're having for sure, if they are simply hot ... depends. In both cases I would put a chipset fans. You can also check at Google with your mainboard model if there are more people with temperature problems.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the different system files missing, it could indeed be a disk related issue. Assuming all of the disks haven't been faulty(possible, but unlikely) then the next thing is cabling or the motherboards controller.

Have you got any other cables you could use to start with?

Comment: Hey thnx for the prompt reply chris, but i have already tried using other cables. could this be an issue wid the motherboard? hw cn i cnfirm this? I need to confirm becouse this happens very randomly and when the maintainence guy observes it 4 a day or 2...it behaves pretty normal. My waranty period's about 2 run out...cn u provide sm more help??

Answer (score 0):

You say you've changed the hard drive.

If you have 2 sticks of RAM, then remove one. Try it.
Remove the other. Try it
See if still a problem.

You say you've tried different cables. (I know IDE cables can often be unreliable maybe SATA ones are more reliable..no doubt you use SATA but still try..) As people have said.

Try putting your hard drive in a different port on the motherboard. It may be one port is faulty, then you'll be a bit more sure it's a motherboard issue and have isolated it a bit.

If still a problem then it makes the motherboard a big suspect. But you won't know for sure.

Normally you can't go further than that. But maybe if you find a way to keep the chipset cool or if you check the temp and find a relationship between that and crashing, then you've hit the bullseye. That would be interesting. But that's a bit experimental, and you seem in a rush.. so

Get the motherboard replaced.. you've probably got enough reason to. Then if the replacement will work, you'll know.